# Why is my height negative if I'm pointing upwards?

Tags: kinematics, coordinate-systems, conventions, projectile

I'm solving this typical problem of finding the height I have to aim my crossbow in order to get to a distance. The maths are OK but since gravity is negative my height is also negative. What am I doing wrong? The value is correct so I assume the problem is that gravity should be positive. But that can't be... can it?
Image is a screenshot from the resolution on YouTube. You can see it's positive but according to their own $g$ should be negative.
 [image: Image is a screenshot from the resolution on YouTube]

Comment: What is to the left of the $``="$ sign obscured by the hand?

Comment: nothing. You mean the box?

Comment: I mean the equation as it is now reads $=-1.25\,\mathrm m$. What's behind this ?

Comment: Your example uses $d_x$ for horizontal distance and $d_y$ for vertical distance.  Because calculus uses this nomenclature, these are bad choices for variable names.

Comment: Please, do not post pictures. Type the question instead (and using MathJax for formulae).  There are many reasons, including facilitation for algorithms and helping users whose device doesn't display them well.

Comment: @Ruslan sorry it's dy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a fixed tension, or a given initial velocity, the point reached by the arrow is determined by the angle with respect to the ground (if there are no friction forces), which we may call $s$.

We know that, on the beginning, velocity vector is the tangent to the aimed point, and extrapolating velocity we will know where to aim. But to extrapolate velocity we need to know it, and we know only $v_x$.

As you have calculated the time and the net travel on $y$ is zero: $$v_y=-\frac{1}{2}a\times t$$

where every value is known. Then using Pythagorean relations we get the angle 
 $s=arc\cos(\frac{v_x}{v})$. Once the $s$ is known you have the second triangle composed by $d_x$ and the angle $s$, where you can determine $d_y$. As expected, this value will be positive.

Answer (score 0):

There is an evident problem with the math: you are not taking into account the initial velocity.

You might say: "of course, it says that we assume a free fall". Yes, but that's the problem. If you suppose a free fall, how can you expect something to go upwards? If your initial height is 0, gravity will take it even lower, so the distance is negative. This makes full sense.

$$y=y_0+v_{oy} t + \frac{at^2}{2}$$

- You are assuming that $y_0=0$, which means you are throwing it from the origin (usually from the floor, but it depends on where you put the RF).
- You are supposing it free-falls. A free fall is a fall. If you fall from y=0, you will end up in a lower level than 0m, that is, a negative height.

---

And why is this happening? Because you are focusing the problem in a wrong way. $d_y$ is not the distance your have to point at. It is the distance travelled by the object.

Aiming to a certain height means changing the **angle** of the initial velocity. That means changing $\theta$, where

$$v_x=v\cdot \cos(\theta)\qquad v_{oy}=v\cdot\sin(\theta)$$

If you want to solve this in terms of height, then just apply trigonometry. 
$\theta=\arctan (H_{aim}/d_x)$

Comment: $y_0=0$ doesn't mean throwing from the floor — it means that the reference frame has zero in $y$ at the height of throwing (this is what the black horizontal line in the illustration may be representing).

Comment: in this case we are not using angles yet. So the math should be ok.

Comment: @Absolutely true. I had supposed it was at the floor because the OP was surprised that a height could be negative. A negative height would only be surprising if it meant "under the ground". But yes, I'm gonna change it. Thanks.